# how to add time to html from python method

Tags: python, django

this is part of a flask application. I would like to get the current time to output anywhere in the form of the html file.

I would like to add the method current_time() in flaskr.py to the anywhere in the from in the attached html file.  Thanks!

flaskr.py

```
import os
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, \
    render_template, flash
from datetime import date
import time

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(
    DATABASE = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'flaskr.db'),    ##in real world apps use instance folders for databases instead
    SECRET_KEY = 'development key',
    USERNAME = 'admin',
    PASSWORD = 'default'
    ))

app.config.from_envvar('FLASKR_SETTINGS', silent=True)

def connect_db():
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv

def get_db():
    if not hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db = connect_db()
    return g.sqlite_db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def close_db(error):
    if hasattr(g, 'sqlite_db'):
        g.sqlite_db.close()

def init_db():
    db = get_db()
    with app.open_resource('schema.sql', mode = 'r') as f:
        db.cursor().executescript(f.read())
    db.commit()

@app.cli.command('initdb')
def initdb_command():
    init_db()
    print('initialized the database.')

@app.route('/')
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, text from entries order by id desc')
    entries = cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('show_entries.html', entries=entries)

@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
        abort(401)
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, text) values (?, ?)',
        [request.form['title'], request.form['text']])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != app.config['USERNAME']:
            error = 'Invalid username'

        elif request.form['password'] != app.config['PASSWORD']:
            error = 'Invalid password'
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash('You were logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))
    return render_template('login.html', error = error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flash('You were logged out')
    return redirect(url_for('show_entries'))

def current_time():
    return date.today()
```

show_entries.html

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% if session.logged_in %}
        <form action="{{ url_for('add_entry') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
            <dl>
                <dt>Title:
                <dd><input type=text size=30 name=title>
                <dt>Text:
                <dd><textarea name=text rows=5 cols=40></textarea>

                <dd><input type=submit value=Share>
            </dl>
        </form>

    {% endif %}
    <ul class=entries>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.text|safe }}
        {% else %}
            <li><em> No entries so far</em>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `datetime.now()` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

...
return render_template(... current_time = datetime.now())
...
```